# Combobox drop down display different to combobox text

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box with a data table as the datasource. The display member is a column that includes formatting, intended to show the data's hierarchy level. For example:

```
Option A
-->Option B
-->Option C
---->Option D
```

Is it possible to have the "hierarchy formatting" displayed in the dropdown, but removed once an item is selected. E.g.

```
 Private Sub cmbProductCategory_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As    EventArgs) Handles cmbProductCategory.TextChanged
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmbProductCategory.Text.Trim()) Then
        cmbProductCategory.Text.ToString().Replace("--", String.Empty).Replace(">", String.Empty).Trim()
    End If     
End Sub'
```

Comment: You would have to draw the items yourself.  If you research the `ComboBox.DrawItem` event then you should be able to find examples.

Answer (score 0):

A combobox has `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties. You can assign something different for both then get the selected item using either `SelectedText` or `SelectedValue` respectively.

E.G.

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "-->Option A"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Option A"
```

Now I'm not sure how you get your data(query) so I don't really know what you get right now or how to display it how you want.